# How to position divs in nice little rows

Tags: html, css

I would like to position 8 divs in the following way:

[image: divs]

Here is my JSfiddle which has all the `div` code: http://jsfiddle.net/XRTh5/

What I would like to do is make the `div`'s behave the same way as on this website with it's icons" http://cyberdust.com/. See how when you re-size the page, the icons shrink and get smaller instead of not changing?

Thanks for the help. I would like to do this only using `div's and not using tables or any old technology like that.

Comment: Don't tell me this is Mark Cuban's app website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `float: left;` to float your items, and percentage based widths for a layout that scales.

Remove heights from your container elements to allow them to expand and fit their contents.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/XRTh5/37/

The site that you referenced uses media queries to adjust styles based on window width. That would also work, but percentages may be a simpler way of achieving your desired result.

[image: Example]

**UPDATE:** using a neat little trick with percentage-based padding and `position: absolute`, you can cause the grid items to maintain an aspect ratio. See fiddle link above.

Comment: Very nice. However, when re-sizing the page, only the widths of the orange `div`'shrink, the heights do not. On the example site I showed, they all shrink equally and maintain their aspect ratio. Can you edit it?

Comment: I'm trying to understand why the `.row` class has `overflow: hidden;` and why it works the way it works. Removing that line just makes the blue and green boxes shrink but the icons stay the same size. What is going on here?

Comment: When items are floated, their container takes the height of its non-floated contents and ignores the height of its floated contents. For some reason, `overflow: hidden` causes it to take the height of its floats, meaning backgrounds and other styling will appear correctly. [Here's an article](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html) on quirksmode about it.

Answer (score 3):

Strongly suggest you look at using a framework to accomplish this just as the reference website uses.

But in general it can be accomplished with css and the `@media (min-width: 768px) {}`
which applies different css styles when the browser viewpoint/window is resized.

There are a couple but for your specific need they use bootstrap.js http://getbootstrap.com/

Comment: Honestly it depends on the specifications for the project. In general I will use bootstrap since the majority of the web projects I work on are "mobile first" applications, it is widely used by others, and is easily maintained via composer. Look at the capabilities of the front-end web frameworks to decide which is best for the project you're working on and what you feel most comfortable with.

Answer (score 2):

The example website you posted is using breakpoints to set the size of the icons to specific values depending on the size of the users viewport.

read up on media queries and you should be able to replicate this very easily.

You could also set the size of your icons to a percentage value rather than a fixed width or height and this would scale dynamically but will not re-flow very gracefully.

Something else to investigate is flexbox as this will flex to fit the available space quite nicely but isn't 100% supported on all browsers.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

if you don't need the gap in between the the rows then a few simple tweaks to your css will do:

```
.main {
    display:table;
    border-spacing:50px;
}

.row {
    display:table-row;
}

.icon {
    display:table-cell;
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/XRTh5/14/)

Otherwise you just need to add and extra closing and opening main div to get the middle gap:

[If you do need the gap in the middle](http://jsfiddle.net/XRTh5/25/)

Comment: but what about having the yellow boxes shrink in size when the page is re-sized?

Comment: For that you would need to set the width of the table to 100% and then remove all widths and heights from your other bits, leavbing a square image with it's width set to 100%: http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/XRTh5/34/

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the following CSS:

```
* { box-sizing: border-box; } //border will not add to element width

.icon {
    width: 25%;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: orange;
    border: 1px solid black;
    float: left; //objects will sit next to eachother
}
```

Also, you way want to set this all up using % values for width/height so that you can get the responsive resizing effect

Answer (score 1):

In answer to your first question, how to make the div, use `float:left` on the icons to make them fit horizontally.
Use relative width's to make them shrink. To make them shrink and realign perfectly, you need to use media queries, which I'll not go into right now. Here's the updated css

```
.main {
    height: 400px;
    width: 100%;/*relative widths*/
    background-color: green;
}

.row {
    width: 100%;/*relative widths*/
    background-color: blue;
}

.icon {
    width: 20%;/*relative widths*/
    height: 120px;
    background-color: orange;
    border: 1px solid black;
    float:left;/*fit horizontally*/
}
.row{
    clear:both;/*To stop the icons from floating*/
}
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mDtjP/

Answer (score 1):

I think that is what you need

```
.row div{
    float:left;
}
```

Just float de divs

http://jsfiddle.net/XRTh5/15/

Answer (score 0):

try this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/XRTh5/9/) i change you code

```
.main {
    background-color: green;
    display:inline-block;
}

.row {
    background-color: blue;
    padding:5px;
}

.icon {
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: orange;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set `float: left` like here: http://jsfiddle.net/XRTh5/10/

```
.icon {
    width: 198px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: orange;
    border: 1px solid black;
    float: left;
}
```

Also remember about decreasing div size to `198px` if you want to fit them in `800px` (you have `2px` border).

Comment: or set `box-sizing: border-box;` and keep the 200px width